# Wordpress sidebar doesn't see parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I have page.php. There is a variable $number. If number is more than zero, I would like to load sidebar.php and print that number in sidebar.

page.php

```
<?php  
$number = 4; 

if($number): ?>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

sidebar.php

```
<?php var_dump($number); ?>
```

Why doesn't sidebar.php see my variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global variable this will help you , check below complete code.

```
<?php  
global $number;
$number = 4; 

if($number): ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php  global $number; 
       var_dump($number); ?>
```

Comment: hands off from bad globals.... very bad approach... rather think about OOP

Comment: if code is in small and functionality is very small then don't need to go with oops, and here user want correction in his code which I did. And this is one solution you can add your solution as well.

Comment: _if code is in small and functionality is very small..._ You never know what will happen with code in future ;) This sounds very lazy....

Comment: I found the another way: include sidebar.php